# Efficient way to select a range of key-value pairs from a Java HashMap

Tags: java

I am trying to come up with an efficient way to select a discrete, but arbitrary range of key-value pairs from a HashMap. This is easy in Python, but seems difficult in Java. I was hoping to avoid using Iterators, since they seems slow for this application (correct me if I'm wrong).

For example, I'd like to be able to make the following call:

```
ArrayList<Pair<K, V>> values = pairsFromRange(hashMap, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap-K-K-).

Comment: @shmosel: technically any `NavigableMap` will do. `TreeMap` is just the most commonly used implementation.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Technically any `SortedMap` will do. But it didn't seem worth dwelling on, considering `TreeMap` and the specialized `ConcurrentSkipListMap` are the only implementations provided by the JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do anything that performs meaningfully better than an `Iterator` to do this with a `HashMap`.

If you use a `TreeMap`, however, this becomes easy: use `subMap(0, 5)` or the like.

Answer (score 1):

Looks straightforward with lambdas (implies iteration of course). `skip(n)` and `limit(n)` should allow to address any slice of the map.

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("k1","v");
m.put("k2","v");
m.put("k3","v");
m.put("k4","v");
m.put("k5","v");

Map<String,String> slice = m.entrySet().stream()
    .limit(3)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue()));

System.out.println(slice);
```

> slice ==> {k1=v, k2=v, k3=v}

```
slice = m.entrySet().stream()
    .skip(2)
    .limit(3)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), x -> x.getValue()));

System.out.println(slice);
```

> slice ==> {k3=v, k4=v, k5=v}

Comment: `HashMap` does not have deterministic iteration order.

Comment: Good to know, thx. OP didn't specify order should be preserved so should work  to just get slices.

Comment: To be clear, in this case I did not need order to be preserved. Info was still useful.